# Slow boot + Weird resolution before login screen

Tags: boot, dmesg

Long story short:
Dual booting, Ubuntu 18.04 (on 200Gb partition HDD) and Windows 10 on SSD.
Device: Asus ROG G751JL
Nvidia Driver: nvidia-driver-418(open source)

My issues are:

1)A long boot time(around 60-70 seconds). On another forum, someone said it is because of linux kernel trying to activate the m1-3 function keys, for 20 seconds, but didn't tell how to fix it. After the login screen, everything works perfectly fine.

2)During the boot time, login screen and after logging off (or shutting down the laptop) the resolution changes. I don't know/understand why.

It almost feels like all the drivers are working only after login.
I am attaching some pictures and data about what I think might help you with a possible fix:

[dmesg](https://pastebin.com/CarXdeVc)

[etc/default/grub](https://pastebin.com/0pAiqyXj)

[grub menu(edit text)](https://ibb.co/8x040qr)

[boot logo](https://ibb.co/qp81vJP)

[shutdown text](https://ibb.co/WBj55BT)

Comment: Regarding the resolution. Make sure the driver is enabled/installed. Here's a link that may help:

https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu/